# Google App Engine, Task Queues

Tags: python, google-app-engine, httpwebrequest, scheduled-tasks

How can I remove a task from a task queue? Is Google App Engine Task Queue removes the task from the queue after it is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task queue API only specifies a function for adding tasks.  It will remove them when they complete.

You can, however, manually remove them using the admin console.

Details: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Managing_Task_Queues

Answer (score 3):

A task is removed from the queue when it executes if and only if it returns an HTTP 200 response.  For any other response, it will be retried until it successfully executes.

As David's answer indicates, they can also be manually removed.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks can be deleted via `delete_tasks` function.

Details:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queues#Queue_delete_tasks